# One function for multiple prefixed hooks in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

As we know the meta data is stored in one column. I found a way how to filter it and get just the value with the following code that I found on some of WP forum:

```
add_filter('woe_get_order_product_value__alg_wc_pif_global', function ($value,$order, $item, $product,$item_meta) {
    $t = unserialize($value);
    if( is_array($t) )
        $value = $t[0]['_value'];
    return $value;
}, 10, 5);
```

Now I am trying to change it so that it will filter not just one field but more, for example I have:

- `alg_wc_pif_global_1`
- `alg_wc_pif_global_2`
- `alg_wc_pif_global_3`
- `alg_wc_pif_global_4`

Any ideas?